# "NoMethodError" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, each

I've been trying to solve [this Codewars problem with Ruby](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57061b6fcb7293901a000ac7/train/ruby) but it keeps giving me this error and I don't know the reason.

```
main.rb:10:in `head_smash': undefined method `each' for "":String (NoMethodError)
from main.rb:80:in `block in <main>'
from /runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:55:in `block in describe'
from /runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:46:in `measure'
from /runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:51:in `describe'
from main.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

My code to solve this problem is this one:

```
 def head_smash(arr)
  arr1 = []
    if arr == []
        return 'Gym is empty'
    elsif arr.is_a?(Integer) == true
        return 'This isn\'t the gym!!'
    else
      arr.each do |i| 
         arr1.append(i.gsub(/O/, ' '))
      end
    end
    return arr1
 end
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: In fairness, this part of the challenge is a bit bogus -- "If the provided array is empty, **or is an empty string**, return 'Gym is empty'". The real problem is supposed to be about handing an **`Array`** input, so why is it asking for some special handling on an empty string? If I were designing this, I'd consider **all** non-array inputs to be invalid, and handle them all the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably this test (see line #64 in the test for that [exercise](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57061b6fcb7293901a000ac7/train/ruby)) that makes your code fail:

```
Test.assert_equals(head_smash(''),'Gym is empty')
```

In that test, the input is an empty `String` but your code doesn't check for string types and at least handles empty Strings. Instead, your code calls `arr.each` when `arr` is a string.

A very simple approach to fix this specific issue would be to change the first condition

```
if arr == []
```

to any of the following

```
if arr == [] || arr == ''

if [[], ''].include?(arr)

if arr.respond_to?(:empty?) && arr.empty?
```